# Reading spring properties from a consuming app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm developing a Java library/package that is meant to be consumed by Spring Boot applications as a jar.

The main driver class relies on a set of props to exist from applicaton.properties, and defines its own set within the repository.

However, I'd like for these properties to be configurable by consuming apps. What's the proper way to structure this?

For example, in the project I have a file

```
public class Properties {
    private int maxConnectingCount; 
    private int maxIdleCount;
    // .. other properties read from application.properties
}
```

The main driver class looks something like this:

```
public class LibraryDriver {

    @Autowired 
    private Properties props
    // do stuff with these props
}
```

How can I make it such that a consuming application can override these properties

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve. Are you importing your library into Spring Boot app to be aggregated with parameters from a properties file and then do something with it?

Comment: I'm building a library that reads from a set of app properties that is defined within the library. In my consuming app, I want to override these properties with the same values from the consuming app's properties file (if they exist)

Comment: @GarRudo I guess the jist of the question is: how do I configure a library to read from a consuming application's properties?

Comment: You can aggregate Objects with parameters during construction or by calling setter methods for each property after construction. A really good way would be to create PropertiesFactory class that handles creation of Properties object and pass it to the Driver object.

Answer (score 3):

I usually do the following is such scenarios:

```
public class Properties {
    private int maxConnectingCount; 
    private int maxIdleCount;

    public Properties(String maxConnectingCount, String maxIdleCount) {
        this.maxConnectingCount = maxConnectingCount;
        this.maxIdleCount = maxIdleCount;
    }
}
```

Then you create the bean like this:

```
@Configuration
public class LibraryDriverConfiguration {

    @Value("${maxConnectingCount}")
    private int maxConnectingCount;

    @Value("${maxIdleCount}")
    private int maxIdleCount;

    @Bean
    LibraryDriver libraryDriver() {
        return new LibraryDriver(new Properties(maxConnectingCount, maxIdleCount));
}
```

I like this approach because it allows your properties to have sensible defaults by defining different constructors.

Another option would be to create a `Property` bean and then autowire it to `LibraryDriver`; something like:

```
@Configuration
public class PropertiesConfiguration {

    @Value("${maxConnectingCount}")
    private int maxConnectingCount;

    @Value("${maxIdleCount}")
    private int maxIdleCount;

    @Bean
    Properties properties() {
        return new Properties(maxConnectingCount, maxIdleCount);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
@Component
public class LibraryDriver {

    private final Properties properties;

    @Autowired
    public LibraryDriver(Properties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I think this would work. Is using @Value the only such way of extracting property values when the exact properties file/path is unknown at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to do is by using @Value()

Suppose you develop a @Component that uses a name property, as shown in the following example:

```
@Component
public class LibraryProperties {
private int active; 
private int idle;
// .. other properties read from application.properties
//
@Value("${name}")
private String name;
}
```

On your application classpath (for example, inside your jar) you can have an application.properties file that provides value for name field. When running in a new environment, an application.properties file can be provided outside of your jar that overrides the name.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! if the "name" property was defined in both environments and I used setters/getters instead of the @Value annotation, which property value would be picked up?